# Navigate using TabbedPage w Prism.Forms

Tags: navigation, xamarin.forms, prism, tabbedpage

How would you implement tabbed navigation using prism.forms (latest) deep linking?

I.E populate a TabbedPage with your prism pages and navigate using Prism when the used clicks a tab.

**ANSWER:**
The great Brian of course provided an answer. To clearify the implementation for those looking to do this.

My main navigation is a `NavigationPage` (which of course can contain my main toolbar icons) where I then navigate to the content page in question:

```cs
navigationService.NavigateAsync("MyNavigationPage/MyMainPage");
```

So what I've done is added a Prism page of type `TabbedPage`. In this I can simply place other Prism pages as children:

```XML
<TabbedPage x:Class="MyApp.MyTabbedPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <MyFirstPrismPage Title="tab 1">
        <MySecondPrismPage Title="tab 2">
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

This allowed me to navigate to "MyTabbedPage/MySecondPrismPage" and both pages were able to resolve their viewmodels!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking a tab is not a navigation action.  That is a tab selection changed action.  Assuming you have populated your TabbedPage with your pages, you can navigate and select a tab by calling NavigateAsync("MytabbedPage/TabToSelect")

Comment: Ok, I figured it out now. First I thought "TabToSelect" ment the ContentPage.Title, since that's the tab name. But now I got it - see above.
Fantastic!